# iPhone sent photo

Tags: iphone, photos

So I received a photo from a friend and I have done this with 3 different photos 3 different friends where I saved the photos weeks after they sent them to me and they show up in a photo stream from a week or month earlier. I am wondering does the iPhone save the photos to your photo stream of when they actually took the photo? Is that why I am getting one showing up in my june photo stream that was sent to me in October?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iMessage picture](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160148/imessage-picture)

Answer (score 1):

The date of a photo is not determined by when it is saved, but rather, the [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data embedded in the photo.